# Rx.Observable validate items in stream (pass or throw)

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

Given an Stream within an Observable, I want to validate/check each item. In case one is broken I want to throw an error via Observable.throw, hence break all further processing.

My clunky solution would be

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs'

inputStream.mergeMap(item => (isValid(item))
    ? Rx.Observable.of(item)
    : Rx.Observable.throw(new Error("not valid"))
)
```

This seems ugly, as it constructs for the positive flow a bunch of unnecessary Observables.

Is there a better way to check items in an Observable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just normal `map` and throw an exception inside it:

```
inputStream.map(item => {
  if (isValid(item)) {
    return item;
  }
  throw new Error("not valid");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you can use `takeWhile` operator to do this. For example;

```
yourObservable.takeWhile(item => {
     //your condition
}).subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

It just takes values while your expression is true. When it becomes false, it stops.

You can learn more from [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html). Also you can check [this page](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) out. I hope it helps!

Comment: This is great for silent validation. Thanks. In this situation I need the error thrown. Thanks still.